# Binding.scala - how to get updating count from Vars

Tags: scala, binding.scala

I have a `Vars` binding statement, like so

```
val data: Vars[Contact] = Vars.empty[Contact]
```

I'm trying to show the number of elements like so:

```
<div>{data.all.bind.size}</div>
```

But this produces a complication error

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[App.this.data.All[App.this.Contact]]
[error]     (which expands to)  com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_ <: App.this.Contact]]
[error]  required: com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_$6]] where type _$6 <: App.this.Contact
[error]         {this.data.all.bind.size}</div>
```

How to make this work?

#### Update

trying to use `String` as type for `Vars` binding, same outcome

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[App.this.data.All[String]]
[error]     (which expands to)  com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_ <: String]]
[error]  required: com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_$6]] where type _$6 <: String
[error]         {this.data.all.bind.size}</div>
```

Note that i'm using Scala.js 1.2, Scala 2.13.3 and
`libraryDependencies += "org.lrng.binding" %%% "html" % "latest.release"`
unfortunately, can't provide scalafiddle since it doesn't support Scala 2.13, instead I created a replica project here-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9dpsa9pz0lejtj/bindingreplica.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: Could you provide the `Contact` description? Or please simplify the example with replacing `Contact` to `String` and check the result. I checked `Vars.all.bind.size` binding and more appropriate `Vars.length.bind` and both are worked (please, see here https://scalafiddle.io/sf/IL27nGa/1).

Comment: No, same result
```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[App.this.data.All[String]]
[error]     (which expands to)  com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_ <: String]]
[error]  required: com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_$6]] where type _$6 <: String
[error]         {this.data.all.bind.size}</div>
```

Note that i'm using Scala.js 1.2, scala 2.13.3 and `libraryDependencies += "org.lrng.binding" %%% "html" % "latest.release"` unfortunately, can't use scalafiddle since it doesn't support Scala 2.13

Comment: The typing issue in `Vars.all.bind` is now fixed in https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/pull/302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `length` for this.

```xml
<div>{data.length.bind.toString}</div>
```

Comment: This fails in a different way-
[error] .../src/main/scala/jstextplayground/app/App.scala:53:27: could not find implicit value for parameter bindableSeq: com.thoughtworks.binding.bindable.BindableSeq.Lt[Int,org.scalajs.dom.Node] (Could not find an instance of BindableSeq for Int)
[error]         {this.data.length.bind}</div>
[error]                           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (jstestgroundJS / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed 17 Oct 2020, 16:59:26

Comment: I guess I need the basic "all.bind" to work, but this fails to compile..

Comment: Please, add `toString` after `this.data.length.bind`.

Comment: I attached a sample project in my question, you can reproduce the compilation issue there

Comment: I have already downloaded your sample project. If you replace `this.data.all.bind.size` with `this.data.length.bind.toString` in your sample project, it compiles without errors. Please check my answer carefully.

Comment: You are correct.. I thought I used that in my test examples as well